# How to store variable after reloading a page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Prestashop 1.6. I want to disable "add to cart" button until the client clicks on the "Save button". So he should input some description in additional fields.

This is my "add to cart" button at start:

```
<button type="submit" name="Submit" class="exclusive" disabled="disabled">
    <span>Add to cart</span>
</button>
```

This part is ok. Now, I have an event on this element:

```
<button class="button btn btn-default button button-small" name="saveCustomization">
    <span>Save</span>
</button>
```

But when I click on the button, I never go inside this function. The saveButton  variable is not set to 1. What am I doing wrong ?

My whole code:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("saveButton", 0);

$(document).ready(function () {

    //init process
    $(window).on("load", function () {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("saveButton") === 1) {
            $('button.exclusive').removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $('button.exclusive').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });

    $('button[name=saveCustomization]').click(function () {
        saveButton = 1;
        sessionStorage.setItem("saveButton", saveButton);
    });
});
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: I think it's working fine https://jsbin.com/todeyir/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I try localStorage. The same results. I check this example but the "add to cart" button is disabled even I click save button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need the `window.load` event, `document.ready` is enough
2. Use `== "1"` instead of `===1`

example:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

      console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("saveButton"));

      //init process    
      if (sessionStorage.getItem("saveButton") == "1") {
        $('button.exclusive').removeAttr("disabled");
      } else {
        $('button.exclusive').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }

      $('button[name=saveCustomization]').click(function() {
        saveButton = 1;
        sessionStorage.setItem("saveButton", saveButton);
      });
    });
```

check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/8563/

Comment: @AlivetoDie Die - thanks I kept trying to format the code but it didn't work

Comment: when you are using 1,2... as an index then you cannot leave space between sentences and number

Answer (score 0):

Two Issues Found in your code.

1. After setting the session storage values, you are not comparing the values. Because you have written conditions inside `window.load()`. After setting new value this function won't trigger.
2. When you set the value in session storage, it will store it as a String. Now you are comparing the value using `===`, which means the type should also match. But as per your code it will never get Succeed. Either you have to change the code like `sessionStorage.getItem("saveButton") === "1"` or use only `==`.

So you have to update your code something like below.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("saveButton", 0);

$(document).ready(function () {

//init process
$(window).on("load", function () {
    checkStatus();
});

$('button[name=saveCustomization]').click(function () {
    alert("came inside");
    saveButton = 1;
    sessionStorage.setItem("saveButton", 1);
    checkStatus();
});
function checkStatus() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("saveButton") === "1") {
        $('button.exclusive').removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $('button.exclusive').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwmnutv3/26/)